# How to create multiple dataframes using nested for loops

Tags: r

the dataset marks

```
X <- c("vijay","raj","joy")

Y <- c("maths","eng","science","social","hindi","physical","sanskrit")    

df <- list()

for (i in X){
  for (j in Y)
  {

    df <- data.frame(subset(marks, name == i & subject == j))
  }
}
```

here I want to create subsets having marks of all subject against each student. Thus we want to have 3 X 7 subsets.
But the code I wrote is giving me single subset. How can solve the problem?

Comment: Because you are updating the same object in each loop

Comment: You can use `outer()` ... or a double `lapply()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outer()` but you have to vectorize the inner function:

```
X <- c("vijay","raj","joy")
Y <- c("maths","eng","science","social","hindi","physical","sanskrit")
set.seed(24)
marks <- data.frame(name = sample(X, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                    subject = sample(Y, 100, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sset <- function(x,y) subset(marks, name == x & subject == y)    
L <- outer(X, Y, FUN=Vectorize(sset, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
L[1,1]
```

The object `L` is a matrix of dataframes.
Here is another solution using a double `lapply()`:

```
L2 <- lapply(X, function(x) lapply(Y, function(y) subset(marks, name == x & subject == y)))
```

The object `L2` is a list of lists.
Here is a variant with for-loops:

```
df <- vector("list", length(X)*length(Y))
l <- 1

for (i in X)  for (j in Y) {
  df[[l]] <- subset(marks, name == i & subject == j)
  l <- l+1
}
```

For subsetting only for existing levels you can simply use `split()`

```
L3 <- split(marks, list(marks$name, marks$subject))
```

The objekt `L3` is a list of dataframes.

Comment: it works, but how can we use for loops in this case.

Comment: hi jogo, if I want apply aggregate function to the columns of dataframes present in the list.

Comment: @ATULMEHRA That is another question. "Aggregating in a list of dataframes". Eventually you can use `split()` or `by()`

Answer (score 3):

We could do this with `expand.grid` to create all the combinations, then loop through the rows of the dataset and `subset` the 'marks' to get a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
dat <- expand.grid(X, Y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lst <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) subset(marks, name == x[1] & subject == x[2]))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(X, Y) %>%
   pmap(~ marks %>%
             filter(name == ..1, subject == ..2))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
marks <- data.frame(name = sample(X, 100, replace = TRUE), 
  subject = sample(Y, 100, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```